# Swapping two nodes

Tags: c

I want to swap two nodes of a linked list, and no I don't want to swap data, I want to change links.

here is what i've done so far.

```
void swap(student * prev_p, student * p, student * prev_q, student *q)
{    
      student *tmp=NULL;

      tmp=p->next;
      p->next=q->next;
      q->next=tmp;

      tmp=prev_p->next;
      prev_p->next=q;
      prev_q->next=tmp;
}
```

then i call this function in bubble/selection sort two swap the two nodes

the probleme is i don't know if my logic works or not, second one in my selection sort function i only have the min pointer and the current one

Comment: "don't know if my logic works or not" - Check.

Comment: *"the probleme is i don't know if my logic works or not"* So write a test case, step through it in the debugger, and see if it works or not.

Comment: well, the test so far did not work, im finding problems keeping track of the previous node of min and current in my sorting function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will only work for this type of chain:

```
... -> prev_p -> p -> ... -> prev_q -> q ->...
```

or

```
... -> prev_q -> q -> ... -> prev_p -> p ->...
```

But won't work if you have these situations:

```
... -> prev_p -> p -> q -> ....
```

or

```
... -> prev_q -> q -> p ->...
```

Using your code, you'll end up with a loop inside your linked list in both situations (`... prev_p -> q -> q` for the first and `... prev_q -> q -> q` for the second situation).

**Before changing the `next` fields of `prev_p` or `prev_q` you first have to check if it isn't respectively `q` or `p`** else you'll end up with the awkward situations described above. So your second part of your function should be something like:

```
if (prev_q == p){
    q->next = p;
else{
    if( prev_q ){
        prev_q->next = p;
    }else{
        // q has no parent -> q was the head  -> p must become new head
    }
}
if (prev_p == q){
    p->next = q;
else{
    if( prev_p ){
        prev_p->next = q;
    }else{
        // p has no parent -> p was the head  -> q must become new head
    }
}
```

**EDIT** if p or q can be the head of the list, they will have no parent. `prev_q` or `prev_p` will then be NULL (see your pastebin)

PS: This problem wouldn't occur if you would swap data instead of swapping links. As you said (in your description) you don't want to swap to data, I will let you consider if you have to change tactics or not.

Comment: it gives me segmentation fault

Comment: please show how you use your code because if all nodes you pass to your function are initialized correctly it cannot give a segmentation fault. The only things getting accessed here are fields! Or do you use some kind of array somewhere??

Comment: The code you just posted was not the same as the code in your question! Please post the correct code following time (or at least the context in which you want to use the code in your question). You can create a pastebin and post the link (in your question if possible).

Comment: In your `swap`-function, in your `while` loops you're setting `prev_p` and `prev_q` on respectively `p` and `q` instead of `k`.

Comment: still gives me segmentation fault :/ would u like to apply changes on it ?
@J.Baoby

Comment: Sorry I had to run somewhere urgently. Have you found where the error is comming from??

Comment: Nope, it still gives me a segmentation fault, the problem is comming from the code you posted up

Comment: how do you see that?? How could you conclude that?? It might help me too

Comment: debugger, it stops at  prev_q->next = p;
and now it's giving me many bad addresses, 

PS: would u like to come codeshare ?